# Can't get React and Flask-CORS to work locally

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors, fetch

I'm trying to get an application with a React/NodeJS frontend and a Flask backend to run locally for development purposes. I've been scouring StackOverflow for the last hour, but I can't seem to get past the CORS-issue. I have:

```
import json
 
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

# Enable cors requests
CORS(app)

# Initiate model

@app.route("/query", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin(origin="*", headers=["Content-Type"])
def query():
    """Endpoint for receiving bot response"""
    print(request)
    query = request.json
    bot_answer = blablagetanswer() ... #filling the json 
    return json.dumps({"botResponse": bot_answer})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True,
    )
```

I have read multiple answers, and tried many variations of CORS handling in Flask (tried with and without the `@cross_origin()` decorater, added `@cross_origin(origin="*")` or even `@cross_origin(origin="*", headers=["Content-Type"])` right under the `@app.route()`), but to no avail.

I even tried adding these two lines to my flask app:

```
app.config["CORS_HEADERS"] = "Content-Type"
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

It also didn't help.

I'm `fetch`ing from React like this:

```
var jsonData = { "lastConversations": [this.state.chatInput] }
console.log("Sending Chat: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2));
fetch('http://my-ip:80/query', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
})
```

and the log does contain the text I want to send, but Chrome just says:

> Access to fetch at 'http://my-ip/query' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What am I missing? This is just for local testing, how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when working with JSON, it's important to make sure you let the other side know that you're sending application/json data. Modifying the fetch like this solved it:

```
var jsonData = { "lastConversations": [this.state.chatInput] }

console.log("Sending Chat: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2));
fetch('http://my-ip:80/query', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {   # this is the key part
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)

})
```

Comment: Too bad this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @robaetem It solved mine...